# How do you prove that no matter whether $P(A)=1$ or $0$, $A$ is independent from $B$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Of course we are assuming that $A$ and $B$ are independent events. I know how to show that if $P(A)=1$ then $P(B)=P(AB)$, but how do we show that if $P(A)=0$?

Comment: Hey there Kyle. You have asked 6 questions now, but you haven't accepted any of the answers given. Please review the answers to your other questions and accept some of the answers.

Comment: According to your title, you're trying to show that $A$ and $B$ are independent. According to your first sentence, you're assuming that $A$ and $B$ are independent. This should be an easy proof then.

Comment: I just realized that Thomas, thanks for the heads up, I'm going to start doing that now. I'm pretty new to using this.

Answer (score 1):

Kyle, from your title, it seems you are asking, if $P(A) = 0$, how can we prove that $A$ and $B$ are independent events?  The condition that must hold for two events, $A$ and $B$, to be independent is

$$P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$$

So, if you want to prove $A$ and $B$ are independent, you need to show this.  In this case, if $P(A) = 0$, what is the right hand side?  And, since $P(AB)$ means the probability of $A$ and $B$ both happening, what do you think $P(AB)$ is when the probability of just $A$ happening is $0$?

Note, in your question, you actually ask something totally different.  You assume $A$ and $B$ are independent and you want to prove $P(B) = P(AB)$.  This is a vastly different question.

Comment: This is not the test of independence.  The test of independence is that $P(A)$ is the same regardless of whether $B$ happens.  It implies that $P(AB)=P(A)P(B)$, but that is not what you asked.

Comment: My appologies everyone, I misunderstood the problem a little and then asked for help the completely wrong way. Thanks for your tries.

Comment: @Ross: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29) uses $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ as the definition. It seems to work better than $P(A)=P(A\mid B)$ especially when one of the events can have probability $0$: If $P(B)=0$, then $P(A\mid B)$ isn't even well defined, but an empty event is clearly independent of anything according to Wikipedia's definition.